# How to add "Read More" Link in woocommerce product page short description and in description tab?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add the more tag in woocommerce product short description and in description tab. The normal `<--more-->` tag doesn't work in wordpress pages.

URL to the page : http://grumpy-albatross.w6.gravitydemo.com/product/custom-cake-printed-boxes/

This is how it should look like [image: short description with read more link] !

Right now it looks like this http://grumpy-albatross.w6.gravitydemo.com/product/custom-cake-printed-boxes/

I tried to add the more `<--more-->` tag that didn't work. I also tried to use this code below that was mentioned in another post ([Limit product short description length in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155544/limit-product-short-description-length-in-woocommerce) ) in function.php file but that didn't work as well.

I want to be able to add the "read more link" in the short description and the long description.

Comment: [Is this what you're trying to accomplish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111205/replace-add-to-cart-button-with-a-read-more-linked-to-product-page-on-shop-pages)

Comment: @WPisforme not really , I don't want to change the buttons, I just like to shorten the product description on the product page with a read more link like shown in the screenshot.