# Customize Add to Cart button on specific WooCommerce product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to change the add to cart button for a specific product category on my WooCommerce archives pages to a "Read more" button that will be linked to the product page *(**but Not** on the single product page itself)*.

(Woocommerce, with Elementor on Wordpress)

Using *"[Replace add to cart button with a read more linked to product page on shop pages in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111205/replace-add-to-cart-button-with-a-read-more-linked-to-product-page-on-shop-pages/46115654#46115654)"* answer code, how to restrict it to only one product category *(the term name is "Classes" in this case)*?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `has_term()` conditional function to target a product category, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product ) {
    if ( has_term( 'Classes', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $button_text = __("Read more", "woocommerce");
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }

    return $button;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Comment: 1+ for you my friend :) you deserve it. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to target a specific product? Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoM. `if (  in_array($product->get_id(), array(58,63,89,145,147,231) ) ) {`  with an array of product ids