# Woocommerce - Redirect Add-to-Cart on Shop page to Product Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to redirect my customers to the product page once they click on the add-to-cart button on the shop page.

The following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}
```

from the following question:

[Replace add to cart button with a read more linked to product page on shop pages in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111205/replace-add-to-cart-button-with-a-read-more-linked-to-product-page-on-shop-pages)

gets the job done. however it completely changes all button labels which is not what I want because I've already changed the "read more" label to "Out of Stock" but this code changes everything to "view product".

I don't want to rename the label. I already have a code that I can easily rename any translation in Woocommerce:

```
add_filter('gettext', x_translate_text , 20, 3);
function x_translate_text ( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

$translation = array (

//'Enter any translation from the translation file in Woocommerce' => 'Enter Your Translation', Example:
'Add to cart' => 'View Product',

);

if( isset( $translation[$text] ) ) {
return $translation[$text];
}

return $translated_text;

}
```

So all I need is a simple redirect from add-to-cart (on the shop page) to product page without changing the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove or comment the 4th the line of code like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
     //the line below is responsible for the button text 
    //$button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">add to cart</a>';

    return $button;
}
```

That code is responsible for the button text or label

or your can change the `$button_text` value to `esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )` which get the button text from woo-commerce. So your code would be like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
        function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
             //the line below is responsible for the button text 
            $button_text = esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() );
            $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">'.$button_text.'</a>';
    
   return $button;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ighofose. your first code didn't work. it renames all labels to Add to Cart. your second one works perfectly. however the class wouldn't match and I had to replace it with the original `button wp-element-button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart`